# Firebase JS library doesn't work with Twitter API v2?

Tags: firebase, authentication, twitter, firebase-authentication

I see this error

`FirebaseError: Firebase: Failed to fetch resource from https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true, http status: 403, http response: {"errors":[{"message":"You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve","code":453}]}  (auth/invalid-credential).     at _errorWithCustomMessage (assert.ts:93:1)     at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:169:1)     at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:189:1)     at async _signInWithCredential (credential.ts:37:1)     at async PopupOperation.onAuthEvent (abstract_popup_redirect_operation.ts:102:1)`

Comment: I would suggest to read the error message: You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve" - You request something you don't have access to.

Comment: The specific issue here is that the Firebase auth is trying to fetch the user email address, and this is only available via a secondary call to the `/1.1/account/verify_credentials` endpoint after the initial authentication request. This is what is failing (and why you need to request electated access to get access to the v1.1 endpoints). User email address is not currently available in the new OAuth 2.0 user authentication scheme with Twitter API v2, but can still be retrieved with OAuth 1.0A and API v2.